# How to handle UnauthorizedAccessException when attempting to add files from location without permissions

Tags: c#

I am trying to get all files from folder this way:

```
try
{
    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
}
catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
{
    throw;
}
```

If my root folder contains a folder for which the user doesn't have permission to access, the `UnauthorizedAccessException` is caught and my array is empty and all the recursion failed.

How can I handle this case and insure that my code ignore locations without permission but add the files from location with permissions?

Comment: I don't see any recursion in your code.

Comment: You'll need to create your own recursion loop and handle each directory on its own (Check for access rights, catch possible exceptions etc.)

Comment: Directory.GetFiles doesn't good enough ? can i have example of how to do it ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

see [SafeFileEnumerator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9746538/fastest-safest-file-finding-parsing) on this other post.  I have used the SafeFileEnumerator code in the past with success.  It prevents loosing the entire enumeration when you simply don't have access to a single file so you are still able to iterate through the files that you can access.

EDIT:  The version I have is slightly different from the one I linked to so let me share the version I have.

```
public static class SafeFileEnumerator
{
    public static IEnumerable<string> EnumerateDirectories(string parentDirectory, string searchPattern, SearchOption searchOpt)
    {
        try
        {
            var directories = Enumerable.Empty<string>();
            if (searchOpt == SearchOption.AllDirectories)
            {
                directories = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(parentDirectory)
                    .SelectMany(x => EnumerateDirectories(x, searchPattern, searchOpt));
            }
            return directories.Concat(Directory.EnumerateDirectories(parentDirectory, searchPattern));
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
        {
            return Enumerable.Empty<string>();
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<string> EnumerateFiles(string path, string searchPattern, SearchOption searchOpt)
    {
        try
        {
            var dirFiles = Enumerable.Empty<string>();
            if (searchOpt == SearchOption.AllDirectories)
            {
                dirFiles = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(path)
                                    .SelectMany(x => EnumerateFiles(x, searchPattern, searchOpt));
            }
            return dirFiles.Concat(Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, searchPattern));
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
        {
            return Enumerable.Empty<string>();
        }
    }
}
```

Example Usage:

```
foreach(string fileName in SafeFileEnumerator.EnumerateFiles(folderPath, "*" + extension, SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
    //Do something with filename, store into an array or whatever you want to do.
}
```

Comment: can you show me please an example how to use this class in order to get all files from dir with out errors ?

Comment: This example will skip any files that you do not have access to, but should return a list of files that are available to be read.  Do not, however, make the assumption that you have write permissions.

Comment: This works perfectly, even in cases where inaccessible nested subdirectories in accessible parent subdirectories are. Which seems to screw most other solutions I found to the original question.

Comment: When I call either EnumerateDirectories(@"C:\Windows", "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories) or EnumerateFiles(@"C:\Windows", "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories), the enumeration starts at "C:\" and not "C:\Windows".

Answer (score 3):

You can use FileSystemInfo objects and recursion to accomplish this:

```
static List<string> files = new List<string>();

static void MyMethod() {
    DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath);
    ProcessFolder(dir.GetFileSystemInfos());
}

static void ProcessFolder(IEnumerable<FileSystemInfo> fsi) {
    foreach (FileSystemInfo info in fsi) {

        // We skip reparse points 
        if ((info.Attributes & FileAttributes.ReparsePoint) == FileAttributes.ReparsePoint) {
            Debug.WriteLine("Skipping reparse point '{0}'", info.FullName);
            return;
        }

        if ((info.Attributes & FileAttributes.Directory) == FileAttributes.Directory) {
            // If our FileSystemInfo object is a directory, we call this method again on the
            // new directory.
            try {
                DirectoryInfo dirInfo = (DirectoryInfo)info;
                ProcessFolder(dirInfo.GetFileSystemInfos());
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                // Skipping any errors
                // Really, we should catch each type of Exception - 
                // this will catch -any- exception that occurs, 
                // which may not be the behavior we want.
                Debug.WriteLine("{0}", ex.Message);
                break;
            }
        } else {
            // If our FileSystemInfo object isn't a directory, we cast it as a FileInfo object, 
            // make sure it's not null, and add it to the list.
            var file = info as FileInfo;
            if (file != null) {
                files.Add(file.FullName);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`MyMethod` takes your selected path and creates a `DirectoryInfo` object with it, and then calls the `GetFileSystemInfos()` method and passes that to the `ProcessFolder` method.

The `ProcessFolder` method looks at each `FileSystemInfo` object, skips the [reparse points](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365503%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and if the `FileSystemInfo` object is a directory, calls the `ProcessFolder` method again - otherwise, it casts the `FileSystemInfo` object as a `FileInfo` object, makes sure it's not null, and then adds the filename to the list.

More reading:

- [FileSystemInfo Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.aspx)
- [DirectoryInfo Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.aspx)
- [FileInfo Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx)

Comment: +1 This is the only code sample that worked for me on an iOS device (Xamarin/Mono), to avoid the app crashing completely on an UnauthorizedAccessException for the Snapshots directory.